# Malformed JSON Feed

Tags: php, json, security

We've been provided a JSON feed which is coming back as invalid as the ',' separators are missing after the {} brackets

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Item 1",
  }
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Item 2",
  }
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Item 3",
  }
]
```

Is there anyway to parse this so it's valid JSON, or do I just need to moan the feed providers? Thanks

Comment: You should nag the providers until they give you a valid feed. An additional problem is a trailing `,` after the last item in each object, that is also not valid JSON. I suppose you could use `preg_replace()` to remove trailing commas before `\s*}` and to insert a comma in between `}\s*{` but I would consider that a last resort. It's better to educate your providers so they don't make this mistake again in the future.

Comment: +1 for "your effort would be much better spent getting your provider to fix the feed than trying to accommodate their mistakes."

Comment: If that's all there is to the feed structure, then you could use `$s = preg_replace('/}(\s*){/', '},$1{', $s);` to add commas between `}` and `{` and `$s = preg_replace('/,(\s*)}/', '$1}', $s);` to remove the trailing commas.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @rickdenhaan. This data provider is not providing JSON. They're providing a custom format that kinda sorta looks like JSON.

The use of standard data formats for data exchange has a *really* good reason: Security. The code used for creating and then ingesting the data is fully debugged. You can use php's `json_decode()` with good confidence that it won't let malicious data through. If you wrote your own decoder for this sorta-JSON, you'd have to either trust your data provider completely, or you'd have to get a white hat hacker to attack your code to make sure it doesn't have vulnerabilities to malicious data.

Use `json_decode()` is much much easier.

And, if a data provider claims to provide JSON, but they don't actually provide compliant JSON, would you trust them? I would not. At best some fool marketroid pressured a developer into releasing something really broken to production.
Get them to fix it.

Comment: Another consideration: At some point, unexpectedly, they might **fix** it, breaking the custom parser.

Comment: Agreed. I bet this data provider has a long way to go before they're offering versioned APIs.